# What does Bertrand Russell mean by saying Christianity nowadays requires us to use a vaguer meaning?

Tags: bertrand-russell

What does Bertrand Russell mean when he said that:

> Nowadays it is not quite that. We have to be a little more vague in our meaning of Christianity.

For better understanding, can you cite any examples in relation to this quote ?

Ref: [Why I Am Not A Christian.](http://www.users.drew.edu/~jlenz/whynot.html) (Paragraph: What is a Christian?)

Comment: Please add a reference to Russell quote, thanks. Is there a word behind *quite* missing?

Comment: What do you mean @joWehler ?

Comment: Please correct the quote. It reads: *Nowadays it is not quite that. We have to be a little more vague in our meaning of Christianity.* (Two sentences)

Comment: Oh sorry because in my book it doesn't have a ".".

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from the text (bolded by me):

> The word does not have quite such a full-blooded meaning now as it had in the times of St. Augustine and St. Thomas Aquinas. ***In those days,* if a man said that he was a Christian it was known what he meant. You accepted a whole collection of creeds which were set out with great precision, and every single syllable of those creeds you believed with the whole strength of your convictions.**
>
> What Is a Christian?
>
> ***Nowadays* it is not quite that. We have to be a little more vague in our meaning of Christianity.** I think, however, that there are two different items which are quite essential to anybody calling himself a Christian. The first is one of a dogmatic nature -- namely, that you must believe in God and immortality. If you do not believe in those two things, I do not think that you can properly call yourself a Christian. Then, further than that, as the name implies, you must have some kind of belief about Christ. The Mohammedans, for instance, also believe in God and in immortality, and yet they would not call themselves Christians. I think you must have at the very lowest the belief that Christ was, if not divine, at least the best and wisest of men. If you are not going to believe that much about Christ, I do not think you have any right to call yourself a Christian.

I think it is quite clear from the text that Russel refers to the Scholastic tradition where Christians were pretty well defined and there had been no pluralism whatsoever blurring the definition. There has been the catholic church and some specific orders within it. That's about it. So nowadays, the definition has to be more vague in order to be applyable to all varieties that are thought under the concept of "Christianity". Think about all the sects, religious communities, churches etc. that are considered "Christian", not to mention evangelists and the variety under that name alone.

One example illustrating this is Eucharist (quotes from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucharist)):

> The Catholic Church teaches that once consecrated in the Eucharist, **the elements cease to be bread and wine and actually become the body and blood of Christ,** each of which is accompanied by the other and by Christ's soul and divinity. **The empirical appearance and physical properties are not changed, but for Catholics, the reality is.**
>
> In the Reformed Churches the Eucharist is variously administered. The **Calvinist view** of the Sacrament sees a real presence of Christ in the supper **which differs both from the objective ontological presence of the Catholic view, and from the real absence of Christ and the mental recollection of the memorialism of the Zwinglians and their successors.**

And this is only one of the many differences presented there.

To take another example out of another religion: Islam for sure had been one canonical religion at one point. This would have been the situation similar to the one Russel refers to when speaking of St. Thomas for Christianity. But look at the variety [presented here](http://www.mideastweb.org/Middle-East-Encyclopedia/islam.htm), some of them do not even consider the other to be true muslims. And I think there will be catholics that do not consider calvinists to be true christians. Nevertheless, they all are muslims respectively christians and the definitions must be applyable for all the varieties.

Comment: Do you have a specific examples about the "specific orders" and can you make it  "vague" (the orders) in order to make it applicable to all varieties of Christianity?

Comment: One example is the variety in the liturgy e.g. in Eucharist, see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucharist). The convictions included differ quite a lot.

Comment: Now I get it, Where the Angelican, Eastern Christianity and many more have different interpretations of the Liturgy in Eucharist.

Comment: @Shulz: Included one striking example from this site regarding convictions into the answer. And yes, if they differ even in the most sacrosanct ritual of Christianity that much, there are many other examples to be found in less substantial parts of the belief.

Comment: "I think you must have at the very lowest the belief that Christ was, if not divine, at least the best and wisest of men. If you are not going to believe that much about Christ, I do not think you have any right to call yourself a Christian." Even this is not sufficient, since Muslims, Bahais, and even some Jews hoold that belief as well. Some level is divinity is necessary.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing: Although the actual content of Russel's definition isn't part of the question: I think it is hard to imagine that Jesus would be held over, e.g. Mohammed for muslims or Moses for jews. "The best and wisest" is quite much to say. But I think Russel may just have left the field where he can be considered an expert here ;)

Comment: One nit-pick: "quite clear from the text that Russel refers to the Scholastic tradition" ... Christianity meant something pretty specific well before Scholasticism (ca 1100). Scholasticism was also a Western Christianity movement - there was little debate at the time that Eastern Christians were still Christians even if they weren't scholastics and didn't agree totally with everything that Western Christians did.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery: While I take your point (thanks for that one!), I really just think that it is the way I said before: Russel cannot be considered an expert in this case. Actually there is a reason why he wrote *The History of **Western** Philosophy* =)

Answer (score 1):

Russell first refers to the time of Augustinus and Thomas Aquinas. Thomas - e.g. in Summa Theologiae - gave a precise system of Christian worldview. It answered nearly every question one could ask about the content of Christian faith.

In Russells' time many Christians did no longer know nor understand the subtleties of Summa Theologiae. But more important, people often did not share any longer a literal understanding of the old myths about e.g., afterlife, which had been painted at the walls of many medieval and renaissance churches. Under these circumstances many people developed their private and sometimes vague interpretation of the details of Christian faith. E.g., ask several Christians about their understanding of what the *hell* is?

Hence Russell sets up to define first a common denominator of Christian belief in his time.

Comment: I like the idea of hell where sect under the concept of Christianity have, different ideas of hell.

Comment: @Shulz I remember the answer of a catholic priest to a question whether the hell exists: "Yes it exists, but it is empty." The answer shows his specific problem: To keep the old words but to change their content.

Comment: To apply Russell's quote. The old world should be kept and the content should be 'universal', under the sect of "Christianity" (to make it vague). Is that right ?

Comment: @Shulz Concerning the concept of hell from my example I would judge more harshly: To keep the word but to discharge its content.

Answer (score -1):

Let me see whether 'winging this answer" is acceptable
I must mention that Bertrand Russell's daughter became a devout Christian, Katherine Tait. There is legitimate and not legitimate diversity among Christians -- I speak from a Catholic viewpoint.
But we must keep in mind the Hierarchy of Truths and the attituded that one should have about the path many people tread.

First, the Hierarchy of Truths does not deny that a truth is a truth and being part of the Faith is important but there is lesser and greater importance
These five foundational truths of revelation provide a framework in which all doctrine finds its proper context. They are:

The Blessed Trinity: God is an eternal loving communion of Father, Son, and Holy Spirit
The Person of Jesus: A divine person who took on human nature in the Incarnation
The Paschal Mystery: the suffering, death, resurrection, and ascension of Jesus Christ
The Dignity of the Human Person: made in the image and likeness of God
The Church: the Body of Christ brought to life in the Holy Spirit

But what I think most illuminating is former anti-Catholic John Henry Newman's views after becoming Catholic. There are 2 quotes. One is about what a Catholic should see in other religions and the second is about what true conversion is
QUOTE 1
I do not undervalue at all the advantage of institutions which, though not Catholic, keep out evils worse than themselves. Some restraint is better than none: systems which do not simply inculcate divine truth, yet serve to keep men from being utterly hardened against it, when at length it addresses them; they preserve a certain number of revealed doctrines in the popular mind; they familiarize it to Christian ideas; they create religious associations; and thus, remotely and negatively, they may even be said to prepare and dispose the soul in a certain sense for those inspirations of grace, which, through the merits of Christ, are freely given to all men for their salvation, all over the earth. It is a plain duty, then, not to be forward in destroying religious institutions, even though not Catholic, if we cannot replace them with what is better; but , from fear of injuring them, to shrink from saving the souls of the individuals who live under them, would be worldly wisdom, treachery to Christ, and uncharitableness to His redeemed.

QUOTE 2
True religion is the summit and perfection of false religions; it combines in one whatever there is of good and true separately remaining in each . . . . So that, in matter of fact, if a religious mind were educated in and sincerely attached to some form of heathenism or heresy, and then were brought under the light of truth, it would be drawn off from error into the truth, not by losing what it had, but by gaining what it had not, not by being unclothed, but by being “clothed upon.” True conversion is ever of a positive, not a negative character . end of quote
In sum, BR is way too general. Most people are a certain kind of Christian and not just generic Christian and nowadays (again from my Catholic view) most people are on the road to fuller Truth and it can't take a lifetime to bubble up to a purer more traditional Catholicism

Comment: That seems to imply that Russel is wrong and the Catholic Church was the only true church based on Catholic Dogma and the personal opinions of two persons. If so, questionable as the claim itself may be, this certainly does not answer in any way what Russel meant when stating what he did. Or am I wrong there?